# NullPointerException DirectionsResponse.getRoutes() on mapbox

Tags: java, android

i'm new to Android/java programming and have a weird problem. My App is working fine on the Android 6p emulator, but when i try it on a physical phone it crashes and returns:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.mapbox.directions.service.models.DirectionsResponse.getRoutes()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.example.kim.testmapkart.MainActivity.finnDistanse(MainActivity.java:144)
                                                                             at com.example.kim.testmapkart.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:90)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21155)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

It referring to line 144, where i think the problem is. But cannot find a solution

[Line 144](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7XsC.png)

Comment: Paste your code,not the picture of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/issues/39

The previous version of MapBox directions didn't support foreign devices. But the problem is fixed now in release 1.1.0.